# select count(*) not behaving correctly after alter table

Tags: sql, db2

UPDATE:

It's seems like I didn't explain myself well enough, the following example is more generic, my original question is at the end of the post.

My PROBLEM is that count(*) is giving 0 in some rows when the documentation says it should give at least 1. As another user [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268933/select-count-not-behaving-as-i-expect-it-to#comment81497928_47269071), this is happening both on v9.7 and v11.1.

Here is a MCVE so people can see what I'm talking about.

I create my tables with this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1
 ( 
     X INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ); 
CREATE TABLE TABLE_2
 ( 
     Y INT NOT NULL 
 ); 
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 
VALUES      (1),
            (2), 
            (3), 
            (4), 
            (5); 
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
VALUES      (1),
            (1),
            (2);
```

If we do this query now:

```
SELECT T1.X, COUNT (*) as c1
from TABLE_1 T1 left join TABLE_2 T2 on (T1.X = T2.Y)
group by T1.X;
```

It gives the expected result with at least 1 in c1 for each row since each dangling tuple is counted.

But if we now alter the tables with this and execute a RUNSTATS (as noted in [mao's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268933/select-count-not-behaving-as-i-expect-it-to#comment81497928_47269071)):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_2 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (Y) REFERENCES TABLE_1 ;
RUNSTATS ON TABLE TABLE_1;
```

Executing exactly the same query, now, gives a DIFFERENT RESULT, when it should give the same result set:

```
SELECT T1.X, COUNT (*) as c1
from TABLE_1 T1 left join TABLE_2 T2 on (T1.X = T2.Y)
group by T1.X;
```

This gives zero in c1 for the dangling tuples when it should give 1. And this is a problem, and it means, (in my opinion at least) that count(*) is not behaving as the documentation says.

If not, please tell me where I'm committing the mistake.

ORIGINAL POST:

I've looked everywhere but neither me nor my professor understand why this is happening. I have the following query:

```
SELECT A.NAME, COUNT(*)
from SCHEMA_1.ACTORS A LEFT JOIN SCHEMA_2.MOVIES M on (M.PROTAGONIST = A.NAME)
GROUP BY A.NAME
```

where NAME is the primary key of ACTORS and PROTAGONIST a foreign key that references NAME. Moreover these two tables are in two different schemas.

In theory I want to get how many times an actor was the protagonist of a movie.
I know that the right way of doing this should be using

```
COUNT(M.PROTAGONIST)
```

but for some reason even COUNT(*) is giving 0 for dangling tuples instead of 1.

What is even more weird is that if I write this:

```
SELECT A.NAME, COUNT(*), AVG(A.AGE)
from SCHEMA_1.ACTORS A LEFT JOIN SCHEMA_2.MOVIES M on (M.PROTAGONIST = A.NAME)
GROUP BY A.NAME
```

or this:

```
SELECT A.AGE, COUNT(*)
from SCHEMA_1.ACTORS A LEFT JOIN SCHEMA_2.MOVIES M on (M.PROTAGONIST = A.NAME)
GROUP BY A.AGE
```

everything is working as expected, without any zero for count(*) in the result.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what do you mean?, you don't have any `actor` on that table that hasn't been a protagonist of a movie?

Comment: And what happens if you use `COUNT(F.PROTAGONIST)` ?  You never told us this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there's not even an `F` table on the sample query

Comment: @Lamak Good point...maybe never tried the correct query.

Comment: Sorry my bad, a mistake when translating, I meant COUNT(M.PROTAGONIST), and it gives the expected result, with zero for dangling tuples.

Comment: a MCVE would help here.

Comment: The only way a `count(*)` return 0 is if you don't have any rows.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the data given...

Comment: I don't understand the left join.  By left join, you return null fields where the protagonist's name is not in the Movie.  Would inner join work better?

Comment: I'm using a left join because I needed to see if an actor was never a protagonist, I'm going to update the question with more specification that I left out the first time because I felt they were unnecessary, but since people are asking for more details I'm going to post those

Comment: That's fine then...  You need to count a column in the right-side table.  See Gordon's answer.

Comment: In your edited question, you write that the same query yields different results before/after the alter table.  I used your testcase and your query and your alter table, and the query returns the same result set before and after the 'alter table'.  Cannot recreate your symptom. Give more details of your Db2 server version/platform/fixpack.

Comment: Gordon's answer doesn't apply in my case, I know what I should do to get the result, I don't know why count(*) is giving 0 when it should give 1.

Comment: I am using DB2 v11.1.0.1527 as client, fixpack "0", on windows 10 64 bit. The server should be v9.7.

Comment: Db2 should not change the result-set if you add the foreign-key constraint and do runstats. If you have a support-contract with IBM for Db2 then you should open a support ticket. If you do not have a support contract, you can put your testcase (as a script) on the IBM developerworks forum for Db2 answers to ask their opinion. With your original testcase I observed the result-set changed if the foreign-key index was created before adding the FK constraint (i.e. no need for runstats), but that behaviour does not exhibit with the simpler testcase for some reason.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help, I will start a thread on developerworks forum and if I discover something useful I will post an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour of count(*) was identified as a bug (present on v9.7, v10.5 and v11.1) on IBM forum where I posted a [question](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/413920/bug-in-db2-count-not-behaving-correctly-after-alte/) after [mao's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268933/select-count-not-behaving-correctly-after-alter-table#comment81663542_47268933) comment.

A "special" build would be required to solve the bug.